# Building Mali Driver without X11

Tags: x11, yocto, mali

I try to build an image for bananaPro without X11 and Wayland support. But I got following error during Mali test binary compilation:

```
make: Leaving directory '/home/yusuf/yocto/poky/bananaProHf/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/sunxi-mali/git-r0/git/include'
make -C test test
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/yusuf/yocto/poky/bananaProHf/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/sunxi-mali/git-r0/git/test'
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mtune=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/home/yusuf/yocto/poky/bananaProHf/tmp/sysroots/bananapro -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -I../include -L../../image/usr/lib -o test test.c -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lX11
In file included from ../include/EGL/egl.h:36:0,
from test.c:32:
../include/EGL/eglplatform.h:89:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'test' failed
```

When I view `0001-fix-test-build.patch` file, I see following lines

```
test: ../config.mk test.c

    -$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ test.c -lEGL -lGLESv2
    +$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I../include -L../../image/usr/lib -o $@ test.c -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lX11
```

Since the image doesn't support X11, I assumed the X11 libraries shouldn't be included. Isn't that true?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Yocto, to build image without X11 and Wayland all you have to do is:

`DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " x11 wayland "`

This will ignore all the x11 and wayland components.

---

Edit: 
The [Sunxi Mali Recipe](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/meta-sunxi/blob/master/recipes-graphics/libgles/sunxi-mali_git.bb) you are using required X11 to compile

```
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "${@base_contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'x11', 'x11', '', d)} \
                  ${@base_contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'wayland', 'wayland', '', d)}"
PACKAGECONFIG[wayland] = "EGL_TYPE=framebuffer,,,"
PACKAGECONFIG[x11] = "EGL_TYPE=x11,,virtual/libx11 libxau libxdmcp libdri2,"
```

One way to work around this is to compile mali with X11 and Wayland, then move all the components to the framebuffer system.

The components that need to move include:

```
${S}/include/EGL/*.h ${D}${includedir}/EGL/
#In the recipe, this is in do_install, 
#what it does it move the file from ${S}/include/EGL/*.h to ${D}${incluedir}/EGL/

${S}/include/GLES/*.h ${D}${includedir}/GLES/
${S}/include/GLES2/*.h ${D}${includedir}/GLES2/
${S}/include/KHR/*.h ${D}${includedir}/KHR/
${S}/egl.pc ${D}${libdir}/pkgconfig/
${S}/gles_cm.pc ${D}${libdir}/pkgconfig/
${S}/glesv2.pc ${D}${libdir}/pkgconfig/

mv ${D}${libdir}/libMali.so ${D}${libdir}/libMali.so.3
    ln -sf libMali.so.3 ${D}${libdir}/libMali.so
for flib in libEGL.so.1.4 libGLESv1_CM.so.1.1 libGLESv2.so.2.0 ; do
        rm ${D}${libdir}/$flib
        ln -sf libMali.so.3 ${D}${libdir}/$flib
    done

${S}/test/test ${D}${bindir}/sunximali-test
```

Comment: I have already added this option to local.conf file,but I am still getting this error.

Comment: You could try the way I did with other recipe.  Just a note that I have not done it with mali recipe.

Comment: I don't fully understand,What should I do?I should compile with X11 and wayland support and change mali recipe's do_install section.Isn't that true?

Comment: The way I did this to some of the program in X11 before is: compile the program with X11 and wayland. So you will discard the `DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11 wayland"` line.  Bitbake the program.   Then move the stuff of the program to the framebuffer system.  How to know which item to move,  you have to look at the recipe do_install and so on...Just to note that I have not done it in Mali and it might not work.